# Several requests at the same time bad SQL results

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo, slim

I am faced with an unknown problem, I created a PHP API (Slim framework + Slim PDO) connected to Mysql. I use Nginx as an HTTP server. The API use a "device-id" header to recognize the client (An android application). The concern is that recently an update of the android application makes that at the launch of this one it makes now 2 asynchronous requests on the result API if the user is unknown I find myself with two entries in the table users carrying the same device-id

In a middleware

```
$user = new User($device_id, $ip);
```

In the user class

```
  function __construct($device_id, $ip)
  {
    $this->_device_id = $device_id;
    $this->_ip = $ip;

    if ($this->isExists())
      $this->updateInfo();
    else
      $this->createUser();
  }

  private function isExists()
  {
    global $db_core;

    $selectStatement = $db_core->select(array('id', 'current_group'))
                        ->from('users')
                        ->where('device_id', '=', $this->_device_id);
    $stmt = $selectStatement->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
      $u = $stmt->fetch();
      $this->_id = $u['id'];
      $this->_current_group = $u['current_group'];
      return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
```

The createUser() function creates an entry in the users table with device-id as well as other information such as date and so on.

[User lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbJR.png)

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If device_id field is supposed to be unique in the table, then add an *unique index* for it.
2. Then you'll be able to run a mysql query ON DUPLICATE KEY, like

   ```
   INSERT INTO users (...) VALUES(:device_id, :ip, ...)
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip = values(ip) , ...
   ```

I don't know if it's possible to run such a query with Slim-PDO, but at least you can go with generic insert and update queries, [using exceptions, as shown in my article](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#catch):

```
$this->_device_id = $device_id;
$this->_ip = $ip;
try {
    $this->createUser();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $search = "!Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry\ .*? for key 'device_id'!";
    if (preg_match($search, $e->getMessage())) {
        $this->updateInfo();
    } else {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

it's very important to update on the certain error only, and re-throw it otherwise.

Comment: Just a quick note: The PDO connection option `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,` must be set so that a `PDOException` is thrown.